# Apache Phoenix 4.7 csvBulkLoad.run() throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-phoenix

We are running a spark streaming job to read from Kafka, convert to csv and then write to Hbase. I am using the API CSVBulkLoad to run a bulk load job. The spark job starts fine and converts to CSV but the csvBulkLoad.run() starts a new MR job but fails with this exception

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvToKeyValueMapper$CsvLineParser.<init>(CsvToKeyValueMapper.java:96)
    at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.CsvToKeyValueMapper.setup(CsvToKeyValueMapper.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1865)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
```

This is my spark job command

```
spark-submit --jars $(echo lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') --class "com.lam.app.Driver" --name "MyBulkLoader" --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-class-path $(echo lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 1g --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 2 --files conf.properties PipeLine-1.0.jar
```

Earlier I used to get another error about missing class *(java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yammer/metrics/core/MetricsRegistry)* but it got resolved after including "--driver-class-path $(echo lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') ". Now we are getting this error about missing CSVFormat class.

My lib directory has all the jar files needed including the commons-csv jar but still I am getting this error. I use maven to build the project. 
Below is the code snippet for running the csvbulkload

```
CsvBulkLoadTool csvBulkLoadTool = new CsvBulkLoadTool();
final org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
System.out.println("ZKQuorum " + this.ZKQUORUM);
conf.set(HConstants.ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM, this.ZKQUORUM);
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", String.valueOf(2181));
conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");

csvBulkLoadTool.setConf(conf);
int exitCode = csvBulkLoadTool.run(new String[] { "--input", "\"" + this.hdfsInputFile + "\"",
    "--table", this.TABLENAME, "--zookeeper", this.ZKQUORUM + ":2181:/hbase-unsecure" });
System.out.println("Return code of WDL bulk load execution " + exitCode);
```

My exitCode is -1 always. Please let me know if i am missing something in my class path

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this finally. I had missed adding phoenix client jar and issue got resolved after that. Hope this tip helps someone who come across similar issue